# Linked List scrolling

Tags: java, linked-list, listitem

I'm trying to create a method that adds an int to the end of an existing linked list.

> Q: Write a method that takes the head of a list, which is NOT a
>   sentinel node, and an int, `n`. The method should move the first n
>   nodes to the end of the list while keeping them in the same  order.
>   For example, if you had a list `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]` and `n = 3`, your
>   method should return the list: `[7, 9, 1, 3, 5]`  (return the head of
>   the modified list).

Here's what I have, the question is on the addLast method:

```
public class ListItem{ 
    public int value; 
    public ListItem next; 

    public ListItem(int value, ListItem next){ 
        this.value = value; 
        this.next = next; 
    }

    public void addFirst(int x){
        head = new ListItem(x, head);
        size++
    }

    public void addLast(int x){
        if(head == null){
            addFirst(x);
        }
        else{
            ListItem p;
            for(p = head; p != null; p = p.next){
                p.next = new ListItem(x, null);
                size++;
            }
        }        
}
```

I'm a little confused as to how the method iterates through the list.  In the for loop, it starts at the head, and scrolls until there is no p.next.  But the method inside looks like it replaces each p.next with the new list item, rather than scrolling through until the end.  What part of the code explains how it skips without adding the new item in each place on the existing list?

Comment: Where did you define the `head` element?

Comment: I believe in the addFirst method?  Unless I messed it up and defining in that method doesn't carry it downwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you define `head` and `size` attributes;

For `addLast` function   `else` part should be as follows.

```
 for(p = head; p.next != null; p = p.next);
 p.next = new ListItem(x, null);
 size++;
```

Comment: (Note the `for ...;`. I find it more eye frapping to use `for ... {}` Or better; `ListItem p = head; while (p.next!= null) { p = p.next; }`)

Comment: @JoopEggen yes, you are right. I just try to make minimum change on existing code.

Comment: Could someone explain the question I had at the bottom?  What part of the code says that it scrolls through until the end rather than replacing each p.next with int x? It looks to me like the for loop starts at the head, goes until p.next is null, and in each instance replaces p with int x.

Comment: The existing code's for loop only runs for once. It never iterates until the end. First and second element will be added correctly, but third element will become second, and you lost the real second element. You always have 2 elements with given code.